# Jooq : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am using RecordMapperProvider to convert my join query jooq record to POJO.

```
Convert.convert(record.getValue("customer_id"), Integer.class);
....
```

and lot of other fields, As I want to configure it for all the column fields, but for this query I am not fetching it and it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

My question is, instead of throwing the exception why don't it just return null ?
So that I could just configure it and fetch data whenever I want.

Comment: it's the normal behavior of an array, if is out of bound it will ever give you an exception. If is IN bounds, but empty, you will have a `null`. These are two very different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nature of the exception has been discussed on the [user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/zP0ITqWhB7Y/a5-sibi8NfcJ) [a couple of times](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/1am_U9ntVoQ/w56a8jULvv8J). There is a pending [issue #2655](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2655) to fix this exception and replace it by a more meaningful one.

> My question is, instead of throwing the exception why don't it just return null ?

The rationale behind this is easy to understand, as you couldn't distinguish between:

- A record containing the column but yielding `null` for that column.
- A record not containing the column.

Comment: Agreed, but I think in both case the java object could just ignore the null objects right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. The exception is thrown to indicate that the column doesn't exist. In most cases, that's a bug in the calling code, so it should be dealt with using an exception. Returning null would be very ambiguous in this case.